How can I prevent React from adding closing HTML tags for self-closing tags?
I have created a React component that makes use of the HTML <picture> and  tags. The component creates several <source> options and has a fallback <img> at the end.
React seems to know that <img> is a self-closing tag when the component is rendered but adds a closing </source> to each use of this HTML element. How would I prevent this behaviour?
In this case I have six variables that contain differently resolution of the image.
<source
   media={`(max-width: 200px)`}
   srcset={`${small_src}, ${small_src2x} 2x`}
/>
<source
   media={`(max-width: 400px)`}
   srcset={`${mid_src}, ${mid_src2x} 2x`}
/>
<img
   src={large_source}
   srcset={`${large_source}, ${large_source 2x} 2x`}
/>

This renders
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="..pathToSmall, ..pathToSmall@2x 2x">
  </source>
  <source 
    media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="..pathToMid, ..pathToMid@2x 2x">
  </source>
  <img
    src="..pathToLarge"
    srcset="..pathToLarge, ..pathToLarge@2x 2x">
</picture>

So, as you can see, <img> correctly renders without a closing tag but <source> adds a closing tag. How can this be changed so as to prevent the rendering of the closing </source>. Although it still works in browsers with the closing tag it is flagged by w3 validation with this closing tag in place.
w3 Validation error
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 200px)" srcset="pic1.jpg, pic1@2x.jpg 2x"></source>
  <source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="pic2.jpg, pic2@2x.jpg 2x"></source>
  
  <img alt="hi" src="pic2.jpg">
</picture>

// Error: Stray end tag source.
https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

React treats <source> as a regular element in JSX and renders it as <source></source> by default, which is valid HTML. However, HTML5 specifications allow <source> to be a void element and recommend self-closing for better compatibility.

@DavidAniebo Thanks. If you run it through the w3 validator it return error "stray end tag". I've updated the question with the code and error.

I haven't double checked, but wouldn't it be srcSet in React?

@DBS You were correct. Both work fine. Build error was somewhere else
